# awk: search patterns in the multi-string file

Tags: awk

My awk script search the log file fro two search patterns and then print strings where it found into another file.

```
awk -F# -v pat1="$search_pattern1" -v pat2="$search_pattern2" '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {if (match($i, "^1\\.[0-9]+\\/\\A "pat1)) {sub(/^1\./, "", $i); sub(/\/.*/, "", $i); if (first == "") first = $i; if ($i in b) {first = $i; exit} a[$i]} else if (match($i, "^1\\.[0-9]+\\/\\A "pat2)) {sub(/^1\./, "", $i); sub(/\/.*/, "", $i); if ($i in a) {first = $i; exit} b[$i] }}} END {if (first == "") print "1"; else print first}' search_file.log
```

I have a question related to :

```
{if (match($i, "^1\\.[0-9]+\\/\\A "pat1))
```

Presently it find the pat1 just near the "/A" for example in the string like

```
06I_nsp5holoHIE_pp2.pdb #1.1/A pat1 NE2
```

How could I modify the regex to be able to find pat 1 either near /A or near /?, so to be able to identify it additionally in the string like:

```
06I_nsp5holoHIE_pp2.pdb #1.1/? pat1 NE2
```

Comment: Please add samples of your input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I modify the regex to be able to find pat 1 either near /A
> or near /?

I would use `[` and `]` with enumerated acceptable characters inside it. Consider simplified example, let `file.txt` content be

```
1.1/A pat1 NE2 
1.1/? pat1 NE2 
1.1/Z pat1 NE2
```

then

```
awk 'match($0,"1\\.[0-9]+\\/[A?]"){print NR, RSTART, RLENGTH}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1 1 5
2 1 5
```

Explanation: I do print number of row, position of start of match, length of match, if match was found. Observe that `?` means literal `?` inside `[` and `]`. You might elect to use `|` (alternative) rather than `[` and `]` but in such case you must escape `?`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'sub("$","\f" index($_,__)) < NF' \
>                                         \
>   FS='^[^#]*.1[.][0-9]+[/][?A][ ]+|[ ]+' __='pat1'
> ```

```
06I_nsp5holoHIE_pp2.pdb #1.1/? pat1 NE2 
                                        32
```

to cross-validate that 32….

> ```
> gcut -c 32- <<< '06I_nsp5holoHIE_pp2.pdb #1.1/? pat1 NE2 '
> ```

```
pat1 NE2
```